# Is there a way to set multiple variables in one SELECT query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

Hello, everybody.

In my SP, there's a SELECT query like this.

```
SELECT val_01, val_02 INTO var_01, var_02 FROM table_name WHERE col_name = condition_01;
```

This query works properly.

But I've added **exit handler for SQLWARNING** and when above SELECT query has no result, it makes SQL WARNING like this and stopped.

> No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed

I've googled and found a way to solve this problem. It is changing the query like this...

```
SELECT var_01 = val_01, var_02 = val_02 FROM table_name WHERE col_name = condition_01;
```

This query works. But there's a difference between original query and modified query.

In SP, original one doesn't throw SELECT query's result. It just put SELECT query's value into variables.

But the latter one throws its SELECT result with variable's value.

**So my cpp code which call SP get wrong value.**

I can change query to..

```
SET var_01 = SELECT val_01 FROM table_name WHERE col_name = condition_01;

SET var_02 = SELECT val_02 FROM table_name WHERE col_name = condition_01;
```

But as you know, this is very inefficient and below query doesn't work.

```
SET var_01, var_02 = (SELECT val_01, val_02 FROM table_name WHERE col_name = condition_01);
```

Is there an efficient way to make same result of original query?

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Then address this specific scenario in your exit handler (e.g. do not exit if the 1st query does not return any records).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more context, it's unclear precisely what you are asking, but if you need to temporarily override the exit handler, nest your query in a new scoping block, with a handler to clear the variables.  (They have to be cleared if inside a loop, or they will still contain their prior values if assigned).

```sql
-- inside existing procedure
BEGIN -- add this and the handler
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET var_01 = NULL, var_02 = NULL;
  SELECT val_01, val_02 INTO var_01, var_02 FROM table_name WHERE col_name = condition_01;
END; -- add this
-- procedure continues here
```

Comment: "Temporarily override the exit handler" is very fresh to me and useful. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

SELECT a, b INTO aa, bb ...

Reference:  See `INTO` in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: My query uses "SELECT value_01, value_02 INTO var_01, var_02 ..." query. And as I mentioned, It works well but it makes SQLWARNING if SELECT has no result set.

Comment: Is `col_name = condition_01` satisfied?

Comment: Sure. "SELECT ... INTO" still makes a warning if there's no result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @var_01 = @var_02 = '';
SELECT _val_01, _val_02 INTO @var_01, @var_02 FROM table_name WHERE col_name = condition_01;

// check whether var_01=='' or length==0 then do what you want
SELECT @var_01, @var_02
// or 
SELECT LENGTH(@var_01)
```

Comment: you are using user-variables not local-variables

Comment: @Milor8, The point of your solution is validation check not a syntax. Ok, thank you for the advice.